# 日本語に少し違和感：「上位の質問」

Tags: 討議, 日本語

トップページの質問リストの上に表示されている「上位の質問」というタイトルに少し違和感を覚えます。英語版は"Top Questions"なのでそれを和訳されたのだと思います。ここのTopというのは「トップページ」などの「トップ」と同じようなニュアンスで、「最初の」とか「先頭の」くらいの意味だと思います。

「上位の質問」というと、何かのランキングの上位というニュアンスが生まれる気がします。トップページの質問リストの表示順は評価の順位に応じて表示されるわけでもないので、「上位」とか「下位」という概念はやはり馴染まないと思います。

よい日本語タイトルのアイディアがなくて申し訳ないのですが、そのまま「トップ•クエスチョン」でもよいかもしれません。

どなたか何かアイディアがあればよろしくお願いします。